# (PHP/MYSQL) Insert Into won't work when inserting large values, no timeout or errors

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, insert-into

I'm working on an AS3 program using flash; in the program, you enter your Username and Password and pick a deck of cards to register; When the register button is clicked, flash sends the username, password, and a long string from the deck of cards, which can reach over 1 MB long (but at the moment, it's only 1 KB long).

To do this, I use the `INSERT INTO` method. This is my code:

```
<?php 

/*
connect to database
*/

include "connect.php";

/*
create POST vars to receive data from flash
*/

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sdTrunkest = $_POST['sdTrunk'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, Trunk) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$sdTrunkest')";
mysql_query($sql); 
exit("result_message=Success");
?>
```

When I run this code while $sdTrunkest is about maybe 100 Bytes long, it runs fine and registers. But when I try running it when $sdTrunkest is about 1 KB, it simply "pretends that it never saw" the `INSERT INTO` line. It doesn't give me a timeout error, and even so I tried using `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`, but it didn't change. In fact, it doesn't give me any errors at all. Is `INSERT INTO` unable to handle long text? And is there a way to fix this?

Thank you in advance ^^

Comment: Are there weird characters in the input?  You should sanitize them http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php.  I'd also suggest looking at the php/apache log

Comment: no errors because you are not using mysql erros .

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: try this `mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());`

Comment: @Justin, it gave me this, although I don't think it's related at all.. Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: There you go, you need to switch to `mysqli_` then, or PDO.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It gave me an error which mysql didn't this time after changing it to mysqli_connect: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'admin'

Comment: Did you use 4 parameters? `mysql_` uses 3 for DB connection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is what I'm using: 

$db_name = "admin";

$db_username = "root";

$db_password = "";

$db_host = "localhost";

mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

Comment: What were you using before the switch?

Comment: The exact same thing, all I did was add the letter i to mysql :P

Comment: Instead of just `mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);` try `$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);` then do 
`mysqli_query($con,$sql);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That gave me a ton of more errors...you know, I don't think the problem is there altogether, as I can login and it works fine, and logging in uses that same connect.php which is using mysql_connect..

Comment: Try this (from the php man page http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php):  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

Comment: That shouldn't have given you any errors. But try Justin's method.

Comment: @Justin As per docs http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php `$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd")` if your comment was for me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- , I found the problem and answered my question below. Thanks alot to the both of you for helping.
One question though, if I did want an apostrophe in the text, and didn't want it screwing up, what do I do? I've already tried \' , no luck.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you found the problem. As for apostrophes, try [`addslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or [`stripslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) - Apostrophes can be a bit of a pain at times, but one of those should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is typically referred to as sanitizing inputs, and was my first comment.  There are several ways to sanitize, but the easiest is to understand is to use mysql_real_escape_string (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Noble, but not the answer to the OP's problem, which has already been solved. This is more fit as a comment. You have enough rep points to do so.

Comment: Changing the data so that it doesn't break the program isn't really a solution, especially in web code where anyone can send you anything

Comment: Sure I'll agree on that point. However and I say this from experience, even when using `real_escape_string()` in regards to apostrophes, doesn't always work. Which is why I have to use other functions in relation with that; strangely enough.

Comment: Yeah, ideally this would be switched over to prepared statements (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or something like that, but mysql_real_escape_string() seemed a good intro to sanity/bounds checking for the OP

Comment: @Justin Strangely, neither `mysql_real_escape_string` nor `addslashes` seem to work, they both give me the same problem as I had the first time caused by the apostrophe. Any ideas?

Comment: Found the reason, I wasn't doing anything with the data returned. My line was `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);` instead of `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);`, my bad :p

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It had little to do with that mysql_connect error, but I might as well change to mysqli to avoid other errors.
Anyways, the problem was with the string itself; Not in its size, but in its contents. One of the cards' names had an apostrophe, which is probably what messed things up. I removed the apostrophe, copied the text and pasted it multiple times to increase the size, and it still worked perfectly.

I guess the reason why this question is asked so frequently is because the more text you add, the more likely you are to make a mistake.

Thank you very much to everyone who commented ^^